# objective c how to get the specific json key value in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

I have json response for all over country related json. My problem is I want to get the  Algeria.png based on id key name and with out using icon name key. Anybody please guide me. And I want to get the image name dynamically not statically. I am using objective c code.

json for  country array is:(

```
    {
    "dial_code" = "+93";
    "icon_name" = "Afghanistan.png";
    id = 1;
    name = Afghanistan;
},
    {
    "dial_code" = "+355";
    "icon_name" = "Albania.png";
    id = 2;
    name = Albania;
},
    {
    "dial_code" = "+213";
    "icon_name" = "Algeria.png";
    id = 3;
    name = Algeria;
},
    {
    "dial_code" = "+1684";
    "icon_name" = "American-Samoa.png";
    id = 4;
    name = "American Samoa";
},
    {
    "dial_code" = "+376";
    "icon_name" = "Andorra.png";
    id = 5;
    name = Andorra;
},
    {
    "dial_code" = "+244";
    "icon_name" = "Angola.png";
    id = 6;
    name = Angola;
},
```

Comment: Try to get based on dial_code, because it's static OR if id == 4 { } else { }.

Comment: thanks for your respoknse dial_code is not static.i want to get the flag name dynamically.. i mean not specific flag name

Comment: `let array.first(where: { guard let name = $0["name"] else { return false }; name == "Algeria" })`?

Comment: lame thanks for your response. i am using objective c . please give the sample code in objective c..and i want to get the country flag name dynamically. not staticlaly

Comment: It's unclear then what's the value you can use to filter. Is it "Algeria"? Is it "3"? But `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` could help you to do that.

Comment: key name should be static in json. else why would anyone use it? i also find it hard to understand what you are asking. do you mean, in one call, the key is icon_name, and next call it is icon_name1.. etc (keep on changing?) what a crazy design!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had array(this is JsonArray) of dictionaries. So

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3]];
       (OR)
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",3];
NSArray *tempArray = [JsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

In tempArray you will get dictionary object.

```
NSDcitionary *dict = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageName = [dict valueForKey:@"icon_name"];
```

Comment: hi phani thanks for your response. but i want to do dynamically bro.. not stastically. can you come to chat.. i want to chat with u..

Comment: What is meant by dynamic. How you want to do search? What is your exact requirement.

Comment: can you create chat room.. i have some doubts bro.. plz

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] here i need to specify the value as dynamic not static..

Comment: for id's i have an array.. for example i want to display india flag then i need to get the id value and pass to nspredicate bro.

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",3]` should crash. You meant `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d",3]` or `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",@(3)]`

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@",countrycodeRefIdArr[i]];
            NSArray *tempArray = [jsonarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];                                                                     i am writing like this .predicate value getting like this id={101}. but tempArray value getting nil...

Comment: phani697@gmail.com. Contact to this mail.